# how to join 2 table column data into single column

Tags: sqlite, join, merge

I did find some examples but they do not merge into single column.
So, I am trying to join 2 table columns data into single column
I have Url1, site1, url2, site2, endurl  5 columns in table1
and keywords column in table2

I want to join or merge these columns into one column like
url1 site1 keywords,url2 site2 keywords endurl  this will convert to a url generation just for understanding.

I tried

```
SELECT table1.Url1, table1.site1, table1.url2, table1.site2, table1.endurl, table2.keywords
    FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.site1 = table2.keywords AND table1.site2 = table2.keywords;
```

want to merge all columns into single column.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably concat those columns into one.

Edit: Now for SQLite

```
SELECT t1.Url1 || ' ' || t1.site1 || ' ' || t2.keywords ||',' ||t1.url2||' '||t1.site2||' '||t3.keywords as column_name
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table2 t3
WHERE t1.site1 = t2.keywords AND t1.site2 = t3.keywords;
```

Comment: I did not get you,  Can you provide full code.

Comment: @Kumark this should be work in Postgres

Comment: yeah, it does not work in sqlite.  I need that code in sqlite only.  and also there is no table3 in this case.  I do not know how above code will work.

Comment: can you provide me working code for SQLite.

Comment: I think u want keywords for each URL so you have to load table 2 twice to combine Url1 with a keyword and Url2 with an other keyword.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is the [format](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#format) function which uses SQLite's [builtin `printf` implementation](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html). So, assuming your columns are all `TEXT` columns, this will give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT format('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s', table1.Url1, table1.site1, table1.url2, table1.site2, table1.endurl, table2.keywords) as my_column
    FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.site1 = table2.keywords AND table1.site2 = table2.keywords;
```

Comment: Result: no such function: format

Comment: Below code does not get keywords column after site1 and site2 of table1 

<pre>SELECT printf('%s %s %s %s %s %s', table1.Url1, table1.site1, table1.url2, table1.site2, table1.endurl, table2.keywords) as my_column
    FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.site1 = table2.keywords AND table1.site2 = table2.keywords;<code>

Comment: I just replaced format with printf and it gives data without keywords after site1 and site2.  Can you please take a look?

Comment: In SQLite you can use the double pipe operator to concat ('||')
You may should take a look at this page: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-string-functions/sqlite-concat/

Comment: did not meet my requirements.